# Query work in localhost, but not in live

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, localhost, live

I need to make iframe url, for example:

```
https://url.com/category/{category_name)/t=desktop || /t=mobile.
```

I'm using MAMP to run my local dev env and i got it working like it should be, when query string is equal to desktop it shows 3 posts and when mobile then only one post. Now the issue is following, when sysadmin is updating pre-live env he can see from logs this error:

```
[Wed Nov 15 20:09:42.122140 2017] [:error] [pid 7776] [client 10.1.2.66:41696] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wpTheme2/single_iframe.php on line 234
```

single-iframe.php full code: https://pastebin.com/MBC6thDW

When i'm trying to go test url i'm either getting Error 500 or header with query function just printed  out.

I'm using PhpStorm IDE and it doesn't show any errors in my code, what i'm missing here?

Comment: you need to check error log file and read what it writes about this error. if to get an error message, it will be easy to solve problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/77yxK1A7 - Full error log, the line it shows is actually correct and when i remove it IDE shows missing endif

Comment: I see $queried_object = get_queried_object(); tree times) Besides found different just in .sponsored-text - why so many same code?

Comment: I'll start refactoring it soon, it was just hot fix for one of projects. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

https://pastebin.com/7ubTY2A4

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
    <?php
    if(get_field('fav_icon', 'option') != ''){
        $favId = get_field('fav_icon', 'option');
        $favDetails = wp_get_attachment_image_src($favId, 'full');
    }
    ?>
    <?php if(!empty($favDetails)): ?>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $favDetails[0]; ?>">
    <?php endif;?>




    <title><?php wp_title();?></title>


    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <!--[if (lt IE 9)&(!IEMobile)]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="enhanced.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iframe.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
    if(is_front_page()){
        $info = get_bloginfo('description');

        echo '<meta name="og:description" content="'.$info.'">';
        echo '<meta name="og:title" content="Website">';
    }
    ?>
    <style>
        .main-header--frame {
            background-color: #a40057;
            margin-bottom: -40px;
        }
        .main-header--frame .categoryTitle {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-top: 19px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .main-header.main-header--frame .container {
            max-width: 1200px;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<header class="main-header main-header--frame">
    <nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="https://stiil.ee" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="logo" alt="logo"
                         class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <h1 class="categoryTitle">Description</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<main class="main-content main-content-inner valitud-content-inner">
    <div class="container">
            <?php
            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
            $taxChilds = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'hide_empty' => true,
                    'child_of' => $queried_object->term_id
            ) ); ?>

            <?php if(isset($_GET) && $_GET['t'] == 'desktop'): ?>
              <div class="category-wrap">
                            <?php
                            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
                            $count =0; 
                            foreach($taxChilds as $taxChild): ?>
                                <?php
                                $args = array(
                                        'post_type'=> 'post',
                                        'cat' => $taxChild->slug,
                                        'posts_per_page' => '1',
                                        'orderby' => 'rand',

                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                                        'hide_empty' => false,
                                                        'terms'    =>  $taxChild->term_id,
                                                ),
                                        )
                                );
                                query_posts($args); if(have_posts()):
                                    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                                        <div class="col-md-4 all itemz <?php echo $taxChild->slug; ?>" data-cat="<?php echo $taxChild->slug; ?>">
                                            <div class="item-wrap">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('size-370x416');
                                                                                $sponsored = get_field('is_sponsored_content');
                                                                                if($sponsored){
                                                                                    echo '<div class="sponsored-text">Ad</div>';
                                                                                };
                                                                                ?></a>
                                                <div class="overlay">
                                                    <div class="notify">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_cat_img_src();?>" alt=""></a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <h2  class="categoryTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endwhile; 

                                endif; wp_reset_query();?>
                                <?php
                                if ($count == 2) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php $count++; endforeach;?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if(isset($_GET) && $_GET['t'] == 'mobile'): ?>
              <div class="category-wrap">
                            <?php
                            $queried_object = get_queried_object();
                            $count =0;  foreach($taxChilds as $taxChild): ?>
                                <?php
                                $args = array(
                                        'post_type'=> 'post',
                                        'cat' => $taxChild->slug,
                                        'posts_per_page' => '1',
                                        'orderby' => 'rand',

                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                                        'hide_empty' => false,
                                                        'terms'    =>  $taxChild->term_id,
                                                ),
                                        )
                                );
                                query_posts($args); 
                                if(have_posts()): 
                                    while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="col-md-4 all itemz <?php echo $taxChild->slug; ?>" data-cat="<?php echo $taxChild->slug; ?>">
                                    <div class="item-wrap">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('size-370x416');
                                                                        $sponsored = get_field('is_sponsored_content');
                                                                        if($sponsored){
                                                                            echo '<div class="sponsored-text">SISUTURUNDUS</div>';
                                                                        };
                                                                        ?></a>
                                        <div class="overlay">
                                            <div class="notify">
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_post_cat_img_src();?>" alt=""></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <h2  class="categoryTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php endwhile; 
                                endif; wp_reset_query();?>
                                <?php
                                if ($count == 0) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php $count++; endforeach;?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</main>
</body>

<!--main-content ends-->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you used `<? endif; ?>` instead of  `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Its working, thank you. IDE didn't validate error because <? ?> tags. Saved my day, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It is because of shorttags.
In your localhost environment using "< ?" is enabled, in your development server it is not enabled. That is the only reason.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

So, just replace "< ?" with "< ?php", and it will work ok.

Comment: I talked with development server sysadmin and indeed that was the issue, thanks again for quick reply. Thank to y'all, i managed to extinguishing this bug quickly. :)